# How to fix broken transform-origin on iOS11 and macOS10.12 Safari?

Tags: ios, css, safari, css-animations

I'm trying to implement CSS animation by using svg.
I am expecting that 2 svg boxes is rotating (spinning) with `transform-origin: center center;` 360 degrees. Looks like it behave what I expected with Chrome and Firefox but not with macOS 10.12 (High Sierra) and iOS 11.0.x and 11.1 beta Safari.
Seems like `transform-origin: center center;` does not work in Safari?

Is there any way to fix this issue?

What I expect:
[image: What I expect]

What I see on Safari:
[image: What I see on Safari]

Here is a sample code

HTML:

```
svg(width=500, height=500, viewBox='0 0 500 500')
  rect(x=100, y=100, width=50, height=100)
  rect(x=400, y=100, width=50, height=100)
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

rect {
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;

  &:nth-child(1) {
    fill: red;
  }

  &:nth-child(2) {
    fill: blue;
  }
}
```

You can see the behavior here by accessing with Chrome and Safari:
https://codepen.io/manaten/pen/aLeXjW

EDIT:

https://codepen.io/manaten/pen/aVzeEK
Another example of the issue. Looks like origin is set to be the center of svg element by Safari.

Comment: Not sure it will make a difference, but have you tried with vendor prefixes?

Comment: Since I use autoprefixer, it should not depend on vendor prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

transform-box: fill-box; seems to solve the issue.

```
rect {
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;

  &:nth-child(1) {
    fill: red;
  }

  &:nth-child(2) {
    fill: blue;
  }
}
```

Your first sample with transform-box:

https://codepen.io/MichaelSchober/pen/QOPbKx

Works on MacOs HighSierra 10.13.1 with Safari 11.0.1

The property is still experimental tough. So make sure to check if you are okay with the browser compabtility:

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box

Answer (score 4):

try transform-box:fill-box;
this defines the layout box, to which the transform and transform-origin properties relate to