# How to stop SVG animation centre changing on browser zoom?

Tags: html, css, animation, safari, transform

Can anyone explain what I need to do to stop the centre of an SVG/CSS animation changing when a user zooms his or her browser?

I have made a very small html web page [here](https://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/%7Elester/for_s_o.html) containing an SVN image which features a CSS animation of a wheel which rotates about its centre, and the centre of rotation is where two lines cross.

At the default zoom level of my browser (Safari 14, OSX) the svg and the animation looks fine  -- by which I mean the rotation is about the right place.  It looks fine on a few phones I've tried it on too.

However if I change the zoom level on my browser (which in safari is done with CMD-"+" or CMD-"-") then the rotation suddenly renders about a different place altogether.  If I return to the normal zoom level (CMD-"0") then all returns to normal.  This happens (on my browser) at even small zoom changes (e.g. 125% or 80%).  Here is a [video showing the problem](https://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/%7Elester/zooming.mov) which I am facing.

In the [linked example](https://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/%7Elester/for_s_o.html) I've tried to remove most extraneous clutter rom the  so that, although it's not an absolutely minimal example, it's pretty close. (It's cut down from a much bigger page .... )

[This issue seems related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43642391/safari-svg-transform-origin-zoom-animation) but I can't make any of the suggestions there work for me.

[This other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46971640/how-to-fix-broken-transform-origin-on-ios11-and-macos10-12-safari) also seems related, but again I can't make any of the suggestions work.

Possibly [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57732067/css-transform-origin-not-working-for-svg-in-safari) could help ...

I have pasted below the key parts so that you can see them here without downloading the file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
         html{font-family: Helvetica; display:inline-block; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;}
svg .pumpVisuals {
  animation: mootate 1s linear infinite;  /* Standard */
  -webkit-animation: mootate 1s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera : see https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-play-and-stop-css-animation-using-jquery.php */
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform-origin: center;
  animation-play-state: running;
}
/* standard */
@keyframes mootate {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mootate {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body> 
<svg width="650" height="409" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <line fill="none" stroke-width="10" stroke-opacity="null" fill-opacity="null" x1="231.35893" y1="210" x2="416.05181" y2="210" id="svg_20" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-linecap="null" stroke="#000"/>
  <line fill="none" stroke-width="10" stroke-opacity="null" fill-opacity="null" x1="315.84148" y1="134.72017" x2="316.37349" y2="284.40486" id="svg_19" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-linecap="null" stroke="#000"/>
  <ellipse fill="#000" stroke-width="0" cx="315.48367" cy="209.99871" class="pumpVisuals pumptoggle" id="svg_17" rx="25.50134" ry="25.00147"/>
  <line fill="none" stroke-width="5" x1="298.49991" y1="194.00004" x2="332.49993" y2="226.00005" class="pumpVisuals pumptoggle" id="svg_31" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-linecap="null" stroke="#ffff00"/>
  <rect stroke="#205bdb" fill="#ffff00" stroke-width="5" x="248" y="11.00003" width="138.00003" height="127.00003" id="boiler_rect"/>
  <rect fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="10" stroke-opacity="null" fill-opacity="null" x="483.00002" y="148.00003" width="0" height="8" id="svg_28"/>

  <ellipse fill="none" stroke="#ffff00" stroke-width="0" cx="103.99255" cy="391.85517" id="svg_40" rx="7.24973" ry="3.62487"/>
  <text fill="#000000" stroke="#ffff00" stroke-width="0" x="228.98606" y="183.48037" class="pumptoggle" id="svg_43" font-size="24" font-family="sans-serif" text-anchor="start" xml:space="preserve">Pump</text>

  <text fill="#000000" stroke="#ffff00" stroke-width="0" x="285.32255" y="81.72969" id="svg_33" font-size="24" font-family="sans-serif" text-anchor="start" xml:space="preserve">Boiler</text>
</svg>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your website and it works fine until 250% zoom rate which is normal because browser gives scroll after these sizes but your element still in the center

Comment: I will add some videos to my question to show that (at least on my browser) the center becomes wrong even on just one increment  up or down (i.e. to about 125% up, or to about 75% down, or thereabouts).  What browser did you use, @EvrenK ?

Comment: I have uploaded a video to https://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/~lester/zooming.mov to illustrate why the problem (at least for me) happens at even small zoom changes ... in Safari 14.0.